# How to generate a sql from the inputs to the method

Tags: java, sql, database

I have my below method which will accept two parameters-

> `final String userId- Primary Key for the database`
>
> `final Collection<String> attributeNames- list of column names that I
>   want to retrieve`

Below is the code

```
public Map<String, String> getAttributes(final String userId, final Collection<String> attributeNames) {

     //Below line doesn't works out the way I wanted
     String query="SELECT" +attributeNames.toString()+ ", * from test where id = "+userId+ ";";
     ResultSet result = CassandraDatastaxConnection.getInstance().getSession().execute(query);
     for (Row rows: result){
         System.out.println(rows.getString("key"));
     } 

    return attributes;
}
```

let's take an example, `userId as 40`

Sample `attributeNames` will look like this-

```
[account, behavior, segmentation]
```

Now I need to generate a SQL corresponding to the inputs. So for above example, sql should look like this-

```
SELECT account, behavior, segmentation from test where id = "40";
```

How can I generate a SQL like this from the above inputs? Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you mean generate? Return it as such or take parameter input and use them in your SQL query?

Comment: By generate I mean, corresponding to the inputs, I should be able to make sql. Take a look at my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like `attributeNames.toString().substring(1, attributeNames.toString().length()-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Change this function

```
public Map<String, String> getAttributes(final String userId, final Collection<String> attributeNames) {
 //Below line doesn't works out the way I wanted
 String query="SELECT" +attributeNames.toString()+ ", * from test where id = "+userId+ ";";
 ResultSet result = CassandraDatastaxConnection.getInstance().getSession().execute(query);
 for (Row rows: result){
     System.out.println(rows.getString("key"));
 } 

return attributes;
}
```

to this

```
public Map<String, String> getAttributes(final String userId, final Collection<String> attributeNames) {

 //Below line doesn't works out the way I wanted
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(attributeNames.size());

 for(int i = 0; i<attributeNames.size();i++)
 {
     sb.append(attributeNames.get(i));
     if(i != attributeNames.size() - 1)
          sb.append(",");
 }
 String query="SELECT" +sb.toString()+ " from test where id = "+userId+ ";";
 ResultSet result = CassandraDatastaxConnection.getInstance().getSession().execute(query);
 for (Row rows: result){
     System.out.println(rows.getString("key"));
 } 

return attributes;
}
```

The modified function runs a loop through the attribute names and constructs the query part as name1, name2, name3, etc and then adds it to the query body. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: You could use a `StringBuilder` for the variable `attrs`, it will be much more efficient that way.